# Finding multiple strings in shell scripts

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to find strings `Error:`, `Error :`, `ERROR:`, `ERROR :` in a given file, if found then go to if block if not found then go to else block.

Below is the logic I had written to perform this operation.

```
#!/bin/bash
file='file.log'
text=`cat $file`
echo $text
if [[ ${text} = *Error:* ||${text} = *ERROR:*|| ${text} = *ERROR :* || ${text} = *Error :* || $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  STATUS=1
  echo "=> string found." 
else
  echo "=> no string found." 
fi
```

Seems like this logic is having issues as its returning below error.

```
syntax error near `:*'
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Why not `grep -iq 'error \{0,1\}:' file.log`?

Comment: Thats indeed a good question, i tried even this it didnt work for me. Please bear with me as i am new to shell scripting.

Comment: if ( grep -iq 'error \{0,1\}:' $value || $? -ne 0; ) ; then
STATUS=1
echo "=> found string." 
else
echo "=> Didnt found string." 
fi

Comment: still its going to else block though string exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you’re looking for is easily expressed in a regex, so you can just use `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file='file.log'

if grep -iq 'error \{0,1\}:' "${file}"
then
  STATUS=1
  echo "=> string found." 
else
  echo "=> no string found." 
fi
```

There’s no need to read the whole file into a variable, nor to check `$?` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do using `grep`, using `-i` for case insensitive matching and `-q` to suppress output:

```
#!/bin/bash
file='file.log'
if grep -iq 'error \?:' "$file"; then
  STATUS=1
  echo "=> string found." 
else
  echo "=> no string found." 
fi
```

The regular expression `error ?:` means: the text `error`, followed by an optional space (indicated by `\?` after the space), followed by `:`.

Comment: thanks thomas, eventhough i updated my logic still its going to else block.

Comment: Sorry, missed a backslash there, fixed now (and tested :)).